# How to make drawn line disappear every x seconds in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing an Android game app with kivy, and want to make my drawn line disappear after x seconds after drawing it.

I've tried, read kivy.doc or google but couldn't find it or idk just being dumb.

```
py.

class Drawing(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

#They are what I've found and tried...

    def i_remove_widget(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.Drawing)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.i_remove_widget(), 1.5)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].self.remove = Clock.schedule_once(self, 1.5)
```

```
kv.
Screen:
    Drawing
```

I expect my drawn line disappear in 1.5 seconds, but nothing happens

Comment: Is this even drawing a line?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    line = touch.ud['line']
    def remove_line(*args):
        self.canvas.remove(line)
    Clock.schedule_once(remove_line, 1.5)
```